# Return type mismatch for operator implementation in unordered_map wrapper

Tags: c++11, templates, stl, unordered-map, const-iterator

I am implementing a simple wrapper on top of std::unordered_map with user-defined hash functions and simple iterator/const_iterator. Most of the parts are working but I am stuck with * and -> operator implementations. The mapping from returns types of unordered_map operators to my wrapper operators are hitting compilation error due to type-mismatch errors.

Basically, both "return internalItr" and "return &(*internalItr)" are hitting type-mismatch. However, for testing sake (commented code), I used a const member variable in the const_iterator class, but then the assignment "return_type = *internalItr" works, which is basically the same type-conversion. But keeping a const member variable in const_iterator is not a solution for me as it will hit other issues due to const-ness in "it=h.begin()". I cannot change any public api signatures due to legacy library code and my options are limited. I am sorry for posting this long code chunk but couldn't find a better way to illustrate my scenario of a std::unordered_map with 3 template parameters. However, I have omitted the non-interesting/working template implementation codes for the sake of brevity, but included all the api's to provide the background.

Your comments are appreciated!

```
template< class Key >
class HashFunction
{
  public:
    HashFunction(){};
    HashFunction( const Key & inKey );
    inline operator unsigned() const
    {
      return hashCode;
    }
    size_t operator()(const Key &inKey) const;
  private:
    unsigned hashCode;
};

template< class Key, class Val, class Hash = HashFunction< Key > >
class unordered_map_wrapper
{
  private:
   typedef typename unordered_map<Key,Val,Hash>::const_iterator int_const_iterator;
   typedef typename unordered_map<Key,Val,Hash>::iterator int_iterator;
  public:
   typedef std::pair< Key, Val > key_value;
   class iterator
   {
     friend class unordered_map_wrapper;
     private:
      iterator( int_iterator & inIterator );
     public:
      iterator();
     private:
      int_iterator internalItr;
   };
   class const_iterator
   {
     friend class unordered_map_wrapper;
     private:
      const_iterator( const int_const_iterator & inIterator );
     public:
      const_iterator();
      const key_value & operator*() const;
      const key_value * operator->() const;
      const_iterator & operator++();
      bool operator!=( const const_iterator & inIterator ) const;
     private:
      int_const_iterator internalItr;
      //const key_value return_type;
   };
   const_iterator begin() const
   {
     return const_iterator( mTable->begin() );
   }
   const_iterator end() const
   {
      return const_iterator( mTable->end() );
   }
   unordered_map_wrapper();
   std::pair< iterator, bool > insert(const key_value & inPair);
  private:
    unordered_map<Key, Val, Hash> * mTable;
};

template< class Key, class Val, class Hash >
unordered_map_wrapper< Key, Val, Hash >::const_iterator::const_iterator()
{
}

template< class Key, class Val, class Hash >
unordered_map_wrapper< Key, Val, Hash >::const_iterator::const_iterator( const int_const_iterator & inIterator ) :
  internalItr( inIterator )
{
}

template< class Key, class Val, class Hash >
unordered_map_wrapper< Key, Val, Hash >::unordered_map_wrapper()
{
    mTable=new unordered_map<Key, Val, Hash>(10);
}

template< class Key, class Val, class Hash >
const typename unordered_map_wrapper< Key, Val, Hash >::key_value & unordered_map_wrapper< Key, Val, Hash >::const_iterator::operator*() const
{
  return *internalItr;
}

template< class Key, class Val, class Hash >
const typename unordered_map_wrapper< Key, Val, Hash >::key_value * unordered_map_wrapper< Key, Val, Hash >::const_iterator::operator->() const
{
  //return internalItr;
  return &(*internalItr);
  //return_type = *internalItr;
  //return &return_type;
}

int main() {
  unordered_map_wrapper<string, unsigned> h;
  unordered_map_wrapper<string, unsigned>::const_iterator it;
  h.insert(std::make_pair<string, unsigned>(string("One"), 1));

  std::cout << "MAP VALUES: " << endl;
  for ( it = h.begin() ; it != h.end(); ++it )
    std::cout << " " << it->first << ":" << it->second << endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Compilation error:

```
error: cannot convert 'const std::pair<const std::basic_string<char>, unsigned int>*' to 'const key_value* {aka const std::pair<std::basic_string<char>, unsigned int>*}' in return
   return &(*internalItr);                            ^
```

or

```
error: cannot convert 'const int_const_iterator {aka const std::__detail::_Node_const_iterator<std::pair<const std::basic_string<char>, unsigned int>, false, true>}' to 'const key_value* {aka const std::pair<std::basic_string<char>, unsigned int>*}' in return
   return internalItr;
      ^
```

I could get around the above above issue by:

```
typedef std::pair< const Key, Val > key_value;
```

But now hitting some other issue. Whenever I add another nonconst-overloaded begin() fn it fails. Why is this not able to pick the correct begin() based on the const-ness which works with a typical STL container?

```
iterator begin()
   {
     return iterator( mTable->begin());
   }
```

The error message is:

```
prog.cpp:159:22: error: no match for ‘operator=’ (operand types are ‘unordered_map_wrapper<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, unsigned int>::const_iterator’ and ‘unordered_map_wrapper<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, unsigned int>::iterator’)
   for ( it = h.begin() ; it != h.end(); ++it )

prog.cpp:75:13: error: invalid initialization of non-const reference of type 
‘unordered_map_wrapper<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, unsigned 
int>::int_iterator& {aka std::__detail::_Node_iterator<std::pair<const 
std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, unsigned int>, false, true>&}’ from an 
rvalue of type ‘std::unordered_map<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, 
unsigned int, HashFunction<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >, 
std::equal_to<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >, 
std::allocator<std::pair<const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, unsigned 
int> > >::iterator {aka std::__detail::_Node_iterator<std::pair<const 
std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, unsigned int>, false, true>}’
      return iterator( mTable->begin());
             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Comment: Please provide [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which includes the only compilation problem you're trying to resolve and nothing else. For example, I believe that you can safely get rid of `HashFunction` and that you also should add some includes in the code to make it spit out the only compilation error you're interested in.

Comment: Also, providing the exact compilation error message will increase the possibility of getting an answer.

Comment: @yeputons: Thxs for your comment. Added the compilation error.

Comment: So you're basically asking how to convert `pair<const A, B>*` which you get from `map::iterator` into `pair<A, B>*` which your wrapper has to provide because of the legacy code?

Comment: If you are truly desperate, you can `reinterpret_cast` and hope for the best: `return reinterpret_cast<const key_value*>(&*internalItr);`. Technically, this exhibits undefined behavior, but it'll most likely work in practice.

Comment: About this last error you've added. Standard library containers have their `iterator` convertible to their `const_iterator`. But yours are not convertible this way. In `it = h.begin()`, apparently `it` is a `const_iterator` but `h` is non-const and so `h.begin()` returns an `iterator`. These are two completely unrelated classes as far as the compiler is concerned; it is up to you to define their relationship.